# How to use AES for end to end encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, aes

So I'm trying to implement a simple end to end encryption scheme where the client performs a handshake with another client by encrypting with its private key, sending the public key over to be encrypted by the second clients private key, decrypted with the private key of client 1 and sent back so client 2 has the public key. I'm using the Aes class provided by C#.Net and can't seem to get it to work properly.

The error I'm getting is in reference to padding and I've seen you can remove the padding completely however I've been told this isn't a good idea. Can anyone explain why? Also how do I know what padding to set my decrypt/encrypt to to be able to view a valid key.

Here's what I have

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Connection c = new Connection();
        Connection d = new Connection();
        var encrypted = c.EncryptMessage("stackoverflow");
        var decrypted = c.DecryptMessage(encrypted);
        var encryptedTwice = d.EncryptMessage(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(encrypted));
        var decryptedOnce = c.DecryptMessage(encryptedTwice);
        var decryptedTwice = d.DecryptMessage(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(decryptedOnce));

        Console.WriteLine("Encrypted: " + System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(encrypted));
        Console.WriteLine("Decrypted: " + decrypted);

        Console.WriteLine("Decrypted twice: " + decryptedTwice);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class Connection
{
    private Aes _encryption;
    Connection()
    {
        _encryption = Aes.Create();
    }
    public byte[] EncryptMessage(string message)
    {
        byte[] encrypted;
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = _encryption.CreateEncryptor(_encryption.Key, _encryption.IV);

        using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                {
                    swEncrypt.Write(message);
                }
                encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
            }
        }



        // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
        return encrypted;


    }
    public string DecryptMessage(byte[] message)
    {
        string decrypted = "";
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = _encryption.CreateDecryptor(_encryption.Key, _encryption.IV);

        using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(message))
        {
            using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                {
                    decrypted = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();

                }
            }


            return decrypted;
        }
    }
}
```

When I attempt to do

```
var decryptedOnce = c.DecryptMessage(encryptedTwice);
```

I recieve "cryptographicexception padding is invalid and cannot be removed".

Comment: AES is a symmetric block cipher. It has no relation to asymmetric cryptography like RSA. They are completely different and are used differently.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, sending files, messaging or something else?

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, AES is a symmetric block cipher and, on its own, is not enough to implement end-to-end encryption.  It can be used as **part** of end-to-end encryption, but requires an asymmetric crypto-system like RSA for the actual "end-to-endness" of the design.  Usually, AES is simply used as the cipher for actual data, where as the exchange of keys between two clients is facilitated by RSA through a mutual server.

Secondly, with regards to your code, your error is in assuming that you can convert random binary data to a string: `System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(encrypted)`

You can't do this.  Converting raw data to UTF8 (what you should be using instead of ASCII) and back again will not always give you the same data back because of how character encodings work.  I suggest instead you use `Convert.ToBase64String`, which converts to base64 format which is **designed for representing binary data as common string characters** and will maintain the data between conversions.

The error about padding here is simply a side-effect of what is written above.  Do not remove the padding.

Lastly, I suggest you do some serious reading into cryptography topics before continuing with this project.  I expect you don't intend to use it in production, but if you do, the code you have above has **many** flaws.  Don't use it in production code.